# declaration for variable in while condition in javascript

Tags: javascript

In essence, I am trying to declare a variable in the condition-part of a while loop in javascript:

```
while (var b=a.pop()) {
  do_sth(b)
}
```

Yet, my browser (firefox) doesn't accept that. Instead I have to go like so:

```
var b
while (b=a.pop()) {
  do_sth(b)
}
```

which works. Is this behaviour expected?

Comment: The 2 below explain variable declaration hoisting but don't explain why you can't declare a variable inside a `while` condition (but you can, for example, in a `for` condition). Did you ever find a good explanation for this?

Comment: Another JS quirk, thats why.

Comment: if I were you, I'd consider (re)accept the answer by Ben Fletcher

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The question is a little dated, but I think the answers all miss an important distinction.  That is, a `while` loop expects an *expression* that evaluates to a conditional, i.e., a boolean or value that can be converted to a boolean. See [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) for details.

A pure assignment (without instantiation) is coerced to a boolean via its default return value (the value of the right-hand-side).

A `var` (or `let` or `const`) is a *statement* that allows an optional assignment but has a return value of `undefined`.

You can easily test this in your console:

```
var foo = 42; // undefined
bar = 42      // 42
```

The return values alone don't answer the question, since `undefined` is falsey, but does show that even if JS let you put a `var` in a conditional it would simply always evaluate to false.

Others have mentioned `for` statements and that they allow declaration and instantiation of variables. This is true, but the [documentation explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) that `for` expects a statement or assigment.

Opinions may vary, but for me all this adds up to an understandable consistency not a quirk in behavior with regard to loops. A `while` loop is better thought of as a looping version of an `if` statement than akin to a `for` loop. If there is quirkiness in all of this, it's the `for` statement's wholesale divergence from the language's normal syntax.

Comment: I was looking for 'why?' javascript doesn't allow const,let,var inside while conditionals and this answered my question. I always found it confusing that the console reported undefined when i created a new variable, rather than the value of the variable.

I still don't see the point of javascript returning undefined; they may as well return the value of the variable, but if it returns undefined, better browsers and compilers error when used in conditionals.

Answer (score 45):

Yes, it is.

If you want to, you can use a `for` loop, like this:

```
for (var b; b = a.pop(); ) {      //Note the final semicolon
    do_sth(b);
}
```

Comment: `for` is syntactic sugar

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho On what planet is one of the most ubiquitous language constructs considered "syntactic sugar"?

Comment: It is a `while` + a declaration + the last statement, made into one bit of sugar. But now I see the big distinction here is that `while` has an *expression* that can not include `var` but a `for` is three *statements* that can have a `var`. So - specifically I was wrong for this language. +1 to you

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho it's called syntax

Comment: ... sugar - Syntax sugar - Kind of (yes mush info in this sentence I know). A `for` statement is actually three statements. In that way the `for` is then syntactic sugar for a `while` where the declarationpart is made outside (and it is in Javascript anyway). And the increment/decrement is made inside the body of while usually as the last statement.

Comment: The Javascript language could be improved by a modification kind of in such way that the `var` is an expression instead of a sentence. It is possible to have expression as sentence in Javascript so a declaration as an expression or sentence should both be legal. If an expresion the assigned value should be a result of the expression.

Comment: Intellij/Webstorm might output a warning, thinking that the single `=` is accidental. Wrapping the assignment in parentheses makes it go away: `for (let b; (b = a.pop());) {`

Answer (score 16):

JavaScript does not have block scope. It has function scope. So to make sure that humans and JavaScript both read the code the same way, you should manually hoist your var declarations right up to the top of functions.

Here's what [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) says about your code:

```
Problem at line 1 character 8: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'var'.
```

Use JSLint, at least while you're learning JavaScript. You'll learn a lot very quickly. It will hurt your feelings.

Comment: This is no longer the case with let

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript doesn't have block scope.  So all `var` declarations are at function scope.  So declaring a variable in a `while` expression doesn't make sense in JavaScript.

Additionally, you should end your statements with a semicolon.  It's not strictly necessary, but it's highly recommended.

Comment: 'JavaScript doesn't have block scope' 2009 was a dark time for JS devs. now JS has lexical environments for blocks