# Where should one declare a variable used in loops?

Tags: javascript

For example in this code:

```
... snip    
      breadthFirst (callback) {
        // let node; // here?
        while (this.queue.length > 0) {
          // let node = this.queue.shift(); // or here?
          callback(node);
          node.childNodes.forEach( (node) => {
            this.queue.push(node);
          });
        }
      }
    }
... snip
```

I could have declared let just outside the while loop or inside the while loop.  I'm not sure which is better.

Note that I am using **let** which has block scope so this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711173/declaration-for-variable-in-while-condition-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is not relevant.

Comment: Limit the scope of your variable, therefore declare it inside the while to save on memory, as long as the variable is not needed outside the while loop

Comment: Can you verify w/ documentation that it is not "re-declared" on each loop iteration?

Comment: @user9723590 variable declaration is a syntactic construct. It makes no sense to ask whether it cab be redeclared at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You generally want to limit the scope of variables as much as possible, as it's a waste of memory to establish variables outside of all scope where they're needed/used.

So I would say the latter is better, inside the while loop, as long as you don't need it again after the while loop.

Comment: Can you verify w/ documentation that it is not "re-declared" on each loop iteration?

Comment: @MikeZuckerman Declarations are processed at compile time, not during execution.

Comment: What I find perplexing then is that it is declared a const.  If there is only one variable processed at compile time ... it must change for each loop iteration, how then can a const work?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a third option, I'd say neither. You're already using modern syntax, so why not use modern iteration constructs, like `for-of`? This lets you more cleanly declare it in the head of the loop.

```
breadthFirst (callback) {
  for (const node of this.queue) {
    callback(node);
    this.queue.push(...node.childNodes);
  }
  this.queue.length = 0;
}
```

This also removed the inner loop by taking advantage of spread syntax with the variadic `.push()` method.

As to whether or not the variable is "redclared" (I assume you're worried about repeatedly creating a new scope), this is going to come down to implementation detail more than documentation.

The `const node` is indeed a per-iteration variable, so that it can be useful for functions declared in the loop, but that doesn't prevent optimizations where the variable would be pre-declared and shared by all iterations in situations like this where there are no closure issues.