# Is it safe to use 'undefined' as sentinel in a Javascript while loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, sentinel

Is it safe to use this kind of loop in Javascript?

```js
denseArray = [1,2,3,4,5, '...', 99999]

var x, i = 0
while (x = denseArray[i++]) {
    document.write(x + '<br>')  
    console.log(x)  
}

document.write('Used sentinel: ' + denseArray[i])
document.write('Size of array: ' + i)
```

It is shorter than a for-loop and maybe also more effective for big arrays, to use a built in sentinel. A [sentinel](https://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/sentinels-in-javascript/) *flags the caller to the fact that something rather out-of-the-ordinary has happened*.

The array has to be a [dense array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030196/what-exactly-is-a-dense-array) to work! That means *there are no other* `undefined` *value except the value that come after the last element in the array*. I nearly never use sparse arrays, only dense arrays so that's ok for me.

Another more important point to remember (thank to @Jack Bashford reminded) is *that's not just undefined as a sentinel. If an array value is 0, false, or any other falsy value, the loop will stop*. So, you must be sure that the data in the array does not have [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) that is `0`, `""`, `''`, ``, `null`, `undefined` and `NaN`.

Is there something as a "out of range" problem here, or can we consider arrays in Javascript as "infinite" as long memory is not full? 
Does undefined mean browsers can set it to any value because it is undefined, or can we consider the conditional test always to work? 
Arrays in Javascript is strange because "they are Objects" so better to ask.

I can't find the answer on Stackoverflow using these tags:  `[javascript] [sentinel] [while-loop] [arrays]` . **It gives zero result**!

I have thought about this a while and used it enough to start to worry. But I want to use it because it is elegant, easy to see, short, maybe effective in big data. It is useful that `i` is the size of array.

**UPDATES**

- @Barmar told: *It's guaranteed by JS that an uninitialized array
  element will return the value undefined.*
- [MDN confirms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements): *Using
  an invalid index number returns undefined.*
- A note by @schu34: It is better to use `denseArray.forEach((x)=>{...code})` optimized for it's use and known by devs. No need to encounter falsy values. It has [good browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Well, that's not **just** `undefined` as a sentinel. If an array value is `0`, `false`, or any other falsy value, the loop will stop.

Comment: Good point! I have to edit :)

Comment: This will work, but it's unidiomatic so other programmers are going to find it confusing. I don't see how it's "more effective" than a `for` loop or using the `forEach()` method.

Comment: It's guaranteed by JS that an uninitialized array element will return the value `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe the conditional can be extended to only test on `undefined` as an alternative to allow other falsy values?

Comment: Any references on w3c or MDN to statements? Good to have in coding conventions manual to convince the safety of program. I think: as simpler code - as safer. Actually I don't lika for-loops and prefer while.

Comment: "Using an invalid index number returns undefined": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Worth noting that most JS devs tend to prefer using higher-order functions to iterate over arrays. Somthing like `denseArray.forEach((x)=>{...code})`

Comment: Yes, I think forEach is well optimized despite high level. Has good support! What I thought about effectiveness was to do the assignment in the conditional instead of closure. And there is no comparision expression.

Comment: "*It is shorter than a for-loop and maybe also more effective*" - it's neither, compared to `for (const x of denseArray)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your code won't be viewed by others later on, it's a good idea to make it as readable and organized as possible. Value assignment in condition testing (except for the increment and decrement operators) is generally a bad idea.

Your check needs to be a bit more specific, too, as `[0, '']` both evaluate to false.

```
denseArray = [1,2,3,4,5, '...', 99999]

for(let i = 0; i < denseArray.length; i++) {
  let x = denseArray[i]
  document.write(x + '<br>');
  console.log(x);
  if (/* check bad value */) break;
}

document.write('Used sentinel: ' + denseArray[i])
document.write('Size of array: ' + i)
```

From my experience it's usually not worth it to save a few lines if readability or even reliability is the cost.

Edit: here's the code I used to test the speed

```
const arr = [];
let i;

for (i = 0; i < 30000000; i++) arr.push(i.toString());

let x;

let start = new Date();

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  x = arr[i];
  if (typeof x !== 'string') break;
}

console.log('A');
console.log(new Date().getTime() - start.getTime());

start = new Date();

i = 0;
while (x = arr[i++]) {
}

console.log('B');
console.log(new Date().getTime() -start.getTime());

start = new Date();

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  x = arr[i];
  if (typeof x !== 'string') break;
}

console.log('A');
console.log(new Date().getTime() - start.getTime());

start = new Date();

i = 0;
while (x = arr[i++]) {
}

console.log('B');
console.log(new Date().getTime() -start.getTime());


start = new Date();

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  x = arr[i];
  if (typeof x !== 'string') break;
}

console.log('A');
console.log(new Date().getTime() - start.getTime());

start = new Date();

i = 0;
while (x = arr[i++]) {
}

console.log('B');
console.log(new Date().getTime() -start.getTime());
```

The for loop even has an extra if statement to check for bad values, and still is faster.

Comment: You missed the assignment so I edited the post to put it in first row of closure. It could also be inside the parentheses.

Comment: Compare `for (let i = 0, x; i < denseArray.length; x = denseArray[i]; i++)` to `let i, x; while (x = denseArray[i++])`. They are pretty equal if data has no false values. Knowing more about big data may increase effectiveness by smart code adjustments. Maybe the while gets faster by skip `i < denseArray.length` test?

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho No, it doesn't get faster. When your `x = denseArray[i]` can access out-of-bounds indices because `i` is not limited to the length of the array, the js engine will need to do the bounds check implicitly when accessing the property. And that's very slow. JS engines are optimised for idiomatic code, not short code.

Comment: JavaScript is pretty smart nowadays, but I tried both a for and a while loop ran on a 30M length string array. I ran the test in node on both versions 3 times after each other just to be sure. The result is (A: for, B: while) A 81 B 88 A 79 B 85 A 80 B 84. It seems like for is more readable **and** faster.

Comment: I added it to my answer

Comment: Me also added a jsperf test to my self-answer that confirme your test - The `for` is slightly faster than `while`. Nice test - I would use performance.now(). +1 for same conclusion as me.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. If you feel that I answered your question properly, I'd appreciate it if you marked my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `javascript assignment in while` gave results:

Opinions vary from [it looks like a common error where you try to compare values](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2576606/edit) to [If there is quirkiness in all of this, it's the for statement's wholesale divergence from the language's normal syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862821/985399). The `for` is syntactic sugar adding redundance. It has not outdated `while` together with `if-goto`.

The question in first place is if it is safe. MDN say: [Using an invalid index number returns undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements) in Array, so it is a safe to use. Test on assignments in condition is safe. Several assignments can be done in the same, but a declaration with `var`, `let` or `const` does not return as assign do, so the declaration has to be outside the condition. Have a comment abowe to explain to others or yourself in future that the array must remain dense without falsy values, because otherwise **it can bug**.

To allow `false`, `0` or `""` (any falsy except `undefined`) then extend it to: `while ((x = denseArray[i++]) !== undefined) ...` but then it is not better than an ordinary array length comparision.

Is it useful? [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151870/985399):

```
while( var = GetNext() )
{
  ...do something with var 
}
```

Which would otherwise have to be written

```
var = GetNext();
while( var )
{
 ...do something
 var = GetNext();
}
```

In general it is best to use `denseArray.forEach((x) => { ... })` that is well known by devs. No need to think about falsy values. It has [good browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility). **But** it is slow!

[I made a jsperf](https://jsperf.com/while-with-sentinel/1) that showed **forEach is 60% slower than while**! The test also show the `for` is slightly faster than `while`, on my machine! See also @Albert answer with a test show that **for is slightly faster than while**.

While this use of `while` is safe **it may not be bugfree**. In time of coding you may know your data, but you don't know if someone copy-paste the code to use on other data.

Comment: I made a self-answer to put my findings instead of adding updates to the question.

Comment: Have now change to forEach in my code! I don't like the extra ')' ! It can be a struggle to put it right among several }}})}}}